# Provide JRE with preinstalled signing CA for Windows

Tags: java, java-web-start, code-signing-certificate

We need to provide to our customers a JRE 8 for starting their WebStart applications. Therefore we also need to provide the signing CA that signed the code they start.

A JRE is available as as tar.gz file that just needs to be extracted. I can call `javacpl.exe` on that "installation" and add the signing CA, but that will change it only for the current user. It is no possible to modify the systems signing CA this way.

Can someone give me an hint on how to provide such a custom signing CA together with that JRE?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be enough to add the trusted certificate into the `lib/security/cacerts`. This can be done using `keytool` command:

```
keytool -import -trustcacerts \
        -keystore ./lib/security/cacerts \
        -storepass changeit \
        -alias TrustedCA -import -file TrustedCACert.cer
```

Comment: I thought so, but what is the password for that truststore? Leaving it empty doesn't work.

Comment: @radlan default password is: changeit, it's part of the answer already

Comment: Oh, I didn't expect this. Thanks. I will try that!